# How to create global variable but without to use "global:"

Tags: powershell

How to create subj, but absolutely the same as `$null`, without any "global:" prefix AND this variable should be available anywhere in such notation, in functions body, for example? *Powershell is 6.0.3 (Linux)*

Comment: As you can see [list of parse time constant variables](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/791159d615adf6cdeb67940413d2e96ea0c61274/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/ast.cs#L8780-L8782) is fixed. So you can not create another variable absolutely the same as `$null`, to be [allowed in class methods](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/791159d615adf6cdeb67940413d2e96ea0c61274/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/SemanticChecks.cs#L1035).

Comment: I'm newbie in PS scripting, but it seems strange: you can not create own constants like `$null` as well as own operators like `-eq`, right? In this case I must use `[MyEnum]::` prefix instead of `$myEnumValue`, no way to avoid it, right? May be MS will include such features in the next versions, PS looks cool, I try to use it in Linux even :)

Answer (score 1):

As for my knowledge this is not possible since you need to define the scope of a variable to use it globally within functions.

It might work to put the variable in a separate .ps1 file and dot-source it in the body and and in every function you want to access its data. But changing the variables value won't be global, therefore it would be "read only".

Comment: May be [this](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/03/26/more-tied-variables-in-powershell/) but it looks very complex.

Comment: Interesting approach @Paul-AG

Answer (score 0):

How about New-Variable cmdlet?

```
 new-variable -scope global -name a -value "One"
```

also, check about_scopes help file

```
get-help about_scopes
```

Comment: Error when access `$a` in the function: `Variable is not assigned in the method.` Needs prefix "global:"

Comment: i dont know wtf are you talking about, this is the answer to your question. at least in the way its being asked